# how does become-user differ bettwen adhoc and playbooks

Tags: ansible, adhoc

Using ansible i am logging in as LDAP user and then sudo/becoming the 'db2inst1' user to run some commands. The adhoc mode runs fine but if I try things using a playbooks I get an error that means I need to add the user to the sudoers files.

This works fine.  (i had to edit some things out :) )

`ansible all -i ftest.lst -e ansible_user=user@a.com -e "ansible_ssh_pass={{pass}}" -e "ansible_become_pass={{test_user}}" -e "@pass.yml" --vpas vault -a ". /home/db2inst1/sqllib/db2profile;db2pd -hadr -alldbs;whoami" -m raw -b --become-user=db2inst1`

But connecting to the same box and using a playbook i get issues.

`ansible-playbook -i ftest.lst -e target=test -e ansible_user=user@a.com -e "ansible_ssh_pass={{pass}}" -e "ansible_become_pass={{test_user}}" -e "@pass.yml" --vpas vault test.yml`

The test.yml has

`become: true`
&   `become_user: "{{ instance }}"`

with the instance = db2inst1 being passed it.

This spits out...
`fatal: [hostname123.a]: FAILED! => {"ansible_facts": {"discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"}, "changed": false, "module_stderr": "Shared connection to hostname123.a closed.\r\n", "module_stdout": "\r\n", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 1}z`

Comment: Can you please explicit in which version of ansible there is a `-vpas` option defined and it is used for? I just pulled the latest ansible-core 2.13.6 to make sure and I don't see it there.

Comment: -sh-4.2$ ansible --version
ansible 2.9.27
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/tmp/.ansible-roy.mcdonnell/tmp/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.5 (default, May 27 2022, 11:27:32) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44)]

Comment: [The option does not exist in ansible 2.9.27 either](https://gist.github.com/zeitounator/4a55b29deea08d76cb11aef51fd50758)

Comment: Sorry, i am not sure what you mean here? What is not supported on that version?

Comment: `--vpas vault` is not an `ansible(-playbook)` option so I don't know how to try to reproduce your above problem => `ansible: error: unrecognized arguments: --vpas vault`